# How to sort rows in datatable in RichFaces?

Tags: java, sorting, jsf-2, richfaces

I tried this

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{myBean.cities}" var="c">

<rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">
 <h:outputText value="City"></h:outputText>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{c.name}"/>
</rich:column>

<rich:column sortBy="#{c.population}">
<f:facet name="header">
 <h:outputText value="Population"></h:outputText>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{c.population}"/>
</rich:column>

</rich:dataTable>
```

but rows aren't sorted.

cities is `List<City>`, `City.population` is int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I investigated that in RichFaces 3.3.3 it was enough to add `<h:form> .. </h:form>` around `rich:dataTable` but in RichFaces 4 I had to also add:

- sortOrder attribute to rich:column
- a4j:commandLink element (within f:facet header) with action pointed at sorting bean to switch asc/desc
- view scoped managed bean SortBean with `org.richfaces.component.SortOrder` properties